# Android ExpandableListView hides Children in Gray

Tags: android, listview, hide, expandablelistview

So im using an ExpandableListView and a custom adapter that extends BaseExpandableListViewAdapter in my application.  But when I click on a Group (that is essentially the parent) it tells the ExpandableListView to expand the group and reveal the children below it.  But the problem is, the children have a grey box over their entire view and you cannot see anyhting but a grey box.  I have no idea why this happens

Note: this only happens on android version lower than 4.0.  it works perfect on android 4.0, but android 2.3.3 and below the grey box appears.  Any idea why?

In my opinion sample code would probably not be necessary because Im guessing it is something to do with the android OS but if any code is needed, please ask me and I will edit the question and post it, Thank you!!

heres is what the grey box looks like, the group (parent) is obviously the thing above the grey box
[image: the names of people have been scribbled out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for anyone who looks at this in the future, I finally figured it out, in my xml file for the layout of the "child" i had clipChildren="true", changed it to false and it worked.